# Why does the figure size change when I use print -dpng and -djpeg?

Tags: matlab, png, jpeg

I have this code:

```
x = 1:1:1000;
Hw = 2;
T1 = 60;
L1 = 100;
eta1 = (Hw/2)*(sin(2*pi*((x/L1)-(1/T1))));

units_out ='centimeters';
width = 8;
height = 6;
typefon = 'Times';
fsize_axis = 8;
fsize_label = 10;

fig1 = figure;
h0 = plot(x, eta1,'r');
ylim([-2 2]);
set(gca,'FontName',typefon,'FontSize',fsize_axis,'FontWeight','bold');
title('Water wave 1');
xl0 = xlabel('x (m)');
set(xl0,'FontSize',fsize_label);
yl0 =ylabel('\eta (m)');
set(yl0,'FontSize',fsize_label);

pos =get(gcf,'Position');
pos(3) = width;
pos(4) = height;

set(gcf,'units','centimeters','Position',pos);
set(gca,'LooseInset',max(get(gca,'TightInset'), 0.02))  
set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto');

print('my_figure', '-dpng', '-r600');
delete(fig1);
winopen('my_figure.png');
```

I got an image of: 8.0 x 6.0 cm; 3.15 x 2.36 inches (I expected this size), but if I only modify the formattype to *–djpeg* of *print* function, I got a graphics file of: 66.7 x 50.0 cm; 26.25 x 19.68 inches. Why does the size change? How can I compute the size of the image, in centimeters, taking into account the resolution of the image?

Comment: Are the pixel dimensions the same?

Comment: @usr2564301: both images have 1890 x 1417 pixels  (2.68 MPixels) (4:3).

Comment: Well there you go. 1890/26.25 is exactly 72, and "72 dpi" is still kind of default for a lot of software if there is no explicit resolution given in a file. So one of your file formats stores resolution (PNG; it's in the specifications), the other does not. As a resolution-less bitmap does not *have* an intrinsic size -- on a high DPI screen it will be small, on a 90s 640x480 monitor it will be *huge* -- the concept of "actual size" is rather fluid.

Comment: @usr2564301: I got it the first question, I understand the reason why the size has changed when I use _-djpeg_ type. But, why does the function _print_ not work when I declare the resolution _('myfigure', '-djpeg', '-r600')_?